# How to redirect page in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, redirect, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web page in jQuery Mobile and I'm redirecting the user to another page through `window.location.replace('#page1')` which works fine on Android and iOS but not on Windows Phone 7 - the URL is updated but doesn't changes the page.

I'm using `window.location.replace` instead of `window.location.assign` or `location.hash` because I'm interested in preventing the user from using the back button.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have exactly the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but solved it by changing the script to

```
$.mobile.changePage(#pageID)
```

Worked great for me, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

just tested this on a lumia900, window.location.replace('#page1') should work fine, and it also fires the onhashchange event i assume drives the change in screen etc...

so my guess, without diving into jquery mobile or setting up a mock site is that either your URL hash is incorrect and it is just working through some dumb luck some of the time

OR

jquery mobile has a bug in it some where that is causing havoc on your setup

here's the test page i used: http://jsbin.com/eqelit/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.location.href="www.google.com"`